# Ghost Mode Feature for Gmail

Tags: gmail

I work for an organization that uses Gmail accounts that allow for multiple users to access an account simultaneously.

Does Gmail have a 'ghost mode' in which emails previously marked as unread remain marked as unread? If so where would I find it?

If an email gets marked as read by me someone else who actually needs to use the information in the email rather than cross-reference it may think someone has already done it.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called [email delegation](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/email-delegation-granting-access-to.html)

The following is a snapshot of the available options when setting up email delegation:
[image: Delegate accesses settings]

1. Go to Settings > Accounts and Import
2. Select `Leave conversation unread when opened by others`

For further details, see the help article in references.

## References

[Set up mail delegation - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en).